# Installation of Natural package in meteor throws uncaught exception

Tags: meteor

I am working on a project based on meteor framework. For natural language facility, have installed natural package using "npm install natural" command. For this, have used following  link "https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural".

When I run the app,it is throwing the following error

--

W20140521-14:22:08.096(1)? (STDERR) /home/priya/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140521-14:22:08.385(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20140521-14:22:08.386(1)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20140521-14:22:08.386(1)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: require is not defined
W20140521-14:22:08.387(1)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/natural/node_modules/apparatus/lib/apparatus/classifier/bayes_classifier.js:23:12
W20140521-14:22:08.387(1)? (STDERR)     at app/node_modules/natural/node_modules/apparatus/lib/apparatus/classifier/bayes_classifier.js:134:3
W20140521-14:22:08.387(1)? (STDERR)     at /home/priya/gbproject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140521-14:22:08.388(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140521-14:22:08.388(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/priya/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140521-14:22:08.388(1)? (STDERR)     at /home/priya/gbproject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8

--
I have not written any code after it's installation, then why showing this error. Googled also but could not get the solution. Any pointers please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**0**: Remove the "node_modules" directory at the root of your application if it exists (it should be created when you run `npm install natural`).

**1**: If you need to install a NPM package with Meteor, I recommend you add the [NPM package](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-npm) with mrt:

`mrt add npm`

**2**: Then, you should add your npm package inside the `packages.json` file (created during step 1 at the root of your application).

```
{
    "natural": "0.1.27",
}
```

**3**: Then, use `Meteor.require('natural')`in your file instead of `NPM.require('natural')`.

**4**: Launch Meteor and check that everything works as expected.

Comment: Hi, while doing step 1, I got the ""error: while building router, error: no such ui package found"". Then searching on net, found that ui is related to blaze-layout so updated to version 0.8.0 from 0.7.0.1. But as usual the syntactical errors getting. Then tried to revert back to previous version, again getting error as said before. And now things are getting worse. Do tell me what should be done.

Comment: I am getting following error :                                                 npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.x, required by meteor-npm@0.1.10
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.3.x, required by meteor-npm@0.1.10
npm ERR! not ok code 0

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package `router`:
error: no such package: 'ui'

While building package `npm`:
error: couldn't read npm version lock information